# facebook ad statistics - facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-java-api

how to fetch the statistics of a particular ad. I guess it actually shows the overall statistics for the whole account.
is there any other way to fetch the details ?